# How can I get a character in Python similar to Pascal readkey

Tags: python, character, pascal

In Pascal I can execute this code to get a character from keyboard input:

```
uses crt;
var ch: char;
begin
    ch := '.';
    while ch <> '\' do
    begin
        ch := readkey;
        writeln( ch );
    end;
end;
```

Is there a similar one in Python? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys    

def prog():    
    char = ""     
    while char != "/":    
        char = sys.stdin.read(1)    
        print char
prog()
```

Comment: Does not work for me - `sys.stdin` has per-line bufferization.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by running `Tkinter` in the background:

```
import Tkinter

def keyPress(event, tk):
    ch = event.char
    if ch == '\\':
        tk.destroy()
    else:
        print ch

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk = Tkinter.Tk()
    tk.bind_all('<Key>', lambda event: keyPress(event, tk))
    tk.withdraw()
    tk.mainloop()
```

(Hacked from: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/post567365.html#post567365)

Answer (score 0):

[raw_input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Then slice the first character.

Comment: `raw_input` and `input` read a whole line (i.e. wait for return key).

Comment: I didn't know how Pascal's readkey worked, I assumed it was return press.

Comment: I don't know Pascal either (at least not enough to know this), but functions that mention "char" usually do just that without waiting for a whole line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `use CRT`; I recommend you to `import pygame` instead.